# Clickable errors in Visual Studio Code with a Makefile

Tags: makefile, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to work on a Makefile based project with Visual Studio Code. I created a task and now I can run make and see the output including a little bit of coloring inside visual studio code. However, I am not able to click on a compile error and have it take me to the corresponding line of code. I think this has to be possible, and I can't imagine it's hard, so I must be missing something obvious.

I can reproduce it with a tiny example:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("jo\n");
  unsigned int u = -999;
  int x;
  if ( u < x )
    printf("really small\n");
  asdfasdfa
#error "nononono"
}
```

**Makefile**

```
all:
    gcc -Werror -Wall -Wextra -o main main.c
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "make",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this very issue in the past by running `gcc` output (both `stdout` and `stderr`) through `sed` or `awk` that converted `gcc` error format into `msvc` error format.

Alternatively, you could try using VS Code, [it supports `gcc` natively](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl).

Comment: You know what, you just made me realize that Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are not the same thing. I've updated my question now to clarify that I am talking about Visual Studio Code.

Now, to your suggestions: awk/sed to msvc sounds like a very clever hack, but it also sounds like a much too complex solution. I guess I rather give up on vsc and try eclipse or qtcreator or something. I also don't feel like going down the gcc natively route ... the Makefile is not trivial and I really don't want to reimplement and maintain a vsc build system next to the official Makefile.